# Check if these tables exist before running query and return different data based on result?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following query which works if the table exists but if not it will error out.

```
WITH allTables AS ( 
  SELECT 
    CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) as app,
    user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS users
  FROM `table.app_events_intraday_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170406' AND '20170406'

  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) as app,
    user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS users
  FROM `table.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170406' AND '20170406'
) 
SELECT 
  app as target,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(users)) AS datapoint_value,
  UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', '20170406')) as datapoint_time
FROM allTables
GROUP BY app
```

This query selects the current day / time frame active user based on `_TABLE_SUFFIX`. The issue is that when a table doesn't exist, it returns this error:

> Error: project:table.app_events_intraday_* does not match any table.

I know it's doing this because that table does not exist. I need to find a way to check if a table exists before querying it. Any help would be great, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH allTables AS ( 
  SELECT 
    CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) AS app,
    user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS users
  FROM `table.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 'intraday_20170406' AND 'intraday_20170406'

  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) AS app,
    user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS users
  FROM `table.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170406' AND '20170406'
) 
SELECT 
  app AS target,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(users)) AS datapoint_value,
  UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', '20170406')) AS datapoint_time
FROM allTables
GROUP BY app
```

or it can be "refactored" into

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH allTables AS ( 
  SELECT 
    CONCAT(user_dim.app_info.app_id, ':', user_dim.app_info.app_platform) AS app,
    user_dim.app_info.app_instance_id AS users
  FROM `table.app_events_*`, UNNEST(event_dim) AS event
  WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170406' AND '20170406'
  OR _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN 'intraday_20170406' AND 'intraday_20170406'
) 
SELECT 
  app AS target,
  COUNT(DISTINCT(users)) AS datapoint_value,
  UNIX_SECONDS(PARSE_TIMESTAMP('%Y%m%d', '20170406')) AS datapoint_time
FROM allTables
GROUP BY app
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to add empty table named for example app_events_intraday_empty with same schema as real table so your query will not be erroring even if real table(s) do not exist

Comment: I have  90+ datasets within bigquery and more are getting added everyday. Is there a way to batch that process?

Comment: you just need to add one empty table! - please clarify if you think otherwise

Comment: I get how this fix would work but I would need to have that table within every dataset on my project. I get a few datasets added per day and I can't be creating this table for each one.

Comment: oh, you might mean how to add one table to each of your 90+ datasets. right?

Comment: That would be correct. Also how to do it everytime a new dataset is made.

Comment: sure. you can use any client of your choice or bq command line to write simple script to "automate" this process - but this sounds to me as a new question for you to ask. if you agree - please  accept/vote and post new question - but I recommend you first to search/try by yourself :o)

Answer (score -1):

One method (there are more) to check if a table exists (on dbo schema):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[YourTableName]') AND [type] in (N'U'))
Begin
--DoSomething
End
```

Comment: I can't quite understand how to use this snippet in real life with bigquery even after googling. Could you provide a example or a link to documentation?